# How to select nodes in array via Python in Nuke?

Tags: python, nodes, nuke

I'd like to select all the nodes created in `createdNodes[]` array in The Foundry Nuke script.

```
createdNodes=[]

for r in ReadList:
    rn = nuke.createNode( 'Read' )
    rn['file'].fromUserText( r )

for i in createdNodes: 
    print i['file'].getValue()
    i.setSelected( True )
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Please rephrase what you are trying to say and provide more details around what you are trying to solve.

Comment: this is a part of a biggest scipt...     createdNodes=[] is an array...  i 'd like to fill the array in the loop and then select all node in this array...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select just one `Grade2` node (for instance) use this command:

```
import nuke

nuke.toNode('Grade2').setSelected(True)
```

If you want to select all `Transform` nodes in the script then use this:

```
for w in nuke.allNodes('Transform'):
    w.setSelected(True)
```

If you want to select all the nodes in the NUKE script including `Viewer` then use this:

```
for a in nuke.allNodes():
    a.setSelected(True)
```

And if you want to select all the nodes in the `createdNodes[]` array then use this:

```
t = nuke.createNode('Transform')
g = nuke.createNode('Grade')
b = nuke.createNode('Blur')
createdNodes = [t, g, b]

for i in createdNodes: 
    i.setSelected(True)
```